# SeekBar is not changing custom progress drawable through Java Code

Tags: progress-bar, android-drawable, seekbar

I have custom progress drawable for seekbar. It's working fine if I put progress drawable in xml file but when I try to change its progress drawable through Java Code, It's showing nothing. Sometimes It appeared but it's not stable.

My SeekBar XML Code:

```
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekMcqBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_tract_unselected"
            android:thumb="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mcqQuestionTv"
```

My Custom progress Drawable:
for Unselected Options: progress_tract_unselected

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <size android:height="40dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
        <stroke android:color="#E0E0E0"
            android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
        <selector>
            <item android:state_enabled="false"
                android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#DDDDDD"/>
                    <size android:height="40dp"/>
                    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="4dp"/>
                    <stroke android:color="#E0E0E0"
                        android:width="1dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </scale>
</item>
```

For Selected and Correct Option: progress_tract_correct_option

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <size android:height="40dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
        <stroke android:color="#E0E0E0"
            android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <scale
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleWidth="100%">
        <selector>
            <item
                android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
                android:state_enabled="false" />
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/option_correct" />
                    <size android:height="40dp" />
                    <corners
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="4dp" />
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </scale>
</item>
```

My Java Code for changing drawable:

```
    String answer = modelAskQuestionAdmin.getAnswer();
    String option1 = modelAskQuestionAdmin.getOption1();
    String option2 = modelAskQuestionAdmin.getOption2();
    String option3 = modelAskQuestionAdmin.getOption3();
    String option4 = modelAskQuestionAdmin.getOption4();
    if(answer.equals(option1)){
        
     holder.option1MCQTv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_option1_primary_color, 0, 0,0);
        holder.seekMcqBar1.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_tract_correct_option));
        holder.option1PercentTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }
    else  if(answer.equals(option2)){
        holder.option2MCQTv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_option2_color_primary, 0, 0,0);
        holder.seekMcqBar2.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_tract_correct_option));
        holder.option2PercentTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    }
    else  if(answer.equals(option3)){
        holder.option3MCQTv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_option3_color_primary, 0, 0,0);
        holder.seekMcqBar3.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_tract_correct_option));
        holder.option3PercentTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    }
    else  if(answer.equals(option4)){
        holder.option4MCQTv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_option4_color_primary, 0, 0,0);
        holder.seekMcqBar4.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_tract_correct_option));
        holder.option4PercentTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    }
```

But Result is like this:

image:
Image  [option 2nd must be green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jxzu.png)

But it showing nothing, I mean it showing no progress bar.

Am I missing anything?
Help me!
It could be a duplicate post but I am unable to co-relate to other posts.
waiting for response!..

Comment: Even I have used Bound method mentioned on this site: https://mytechead.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/set-resource-of-setprogressdrawable-programmatically/#respond But nothing is changed. It's not setting progress Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, But this wasn't also working

Rect bounds2 = holder.seekMcqBar2.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
holder.seekMcqBar2.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_tract_correct_option));
holder.seekMcqBar2.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds2);

But Only Solution I have found is this:

```
        holder.seekMcqBar2.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#8000897B"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

But in this We have to put color Manually...

Hope Anyone have any improvised solution to this problem.